# foreach/SNOW/doSNOW verbose output with RTerm, but not RGui

Tags: r, snow

Something magical just happened.  I used Rterm (launched with R.exe) instead of RGui or RStudio to run a parallel task using foreach/snow/doSnow.  In the command window, I can see the output of the child tasks.  This never worked with RGui nor RStudio (which made debugging a pain).  I'm just curious - why?  Literally nothing has changed about my code other than running it in RTerm for the first time.  I'm sure there's some technical nugget I'm missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Rgui and RStudio have controlling event loops for the GUI interaction; Rterm does not.

Comment: any pointers so that I can dig deeper on this topic (R-specific or not)?  I googled some terms from your post but nothing popped.  Would like to understand other consequences of using RGui v. RTerm to inform future use of both.

Comment: Emails by Simon Urbanek to the r-devel mailing list are a good start, and/or other r-devel threads involving discussions of event loops (frequently in the context of GUIs).

Comment: Wht's the difference between snowfall and doSnow?